# How do I use a computed column specification to persist a datetime value using getdate()?

Tags: sql-server

Does anyone know if there is a way to achieve the same affect as a `datetime` column with a default binding of `getdate()` with computed columns?

I have tried setting the formula to `getdate()` and persist to `Yes` but I get an error

`Computed column 'InsertDateTime' in table 'Tmp_Table' cannot be persisted because the column is non-deterministic.`

Comment: What do you want it to contain? If time now then it can't be persisted (stored data) as obviously it will need continually updating. Are you trying to record row created or row updated time?

Comment: Why wouldn't you just make it a non nullable regular column with a default of `getdate()`?

Comment: I admit I have a somewhat silly reason: I am using Entity Framework 4 and I am looking for a way to avoid having to manually set the `StoreGeneratedPattern` attribute to `Computed` on just about every table every time I rebuild the model.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

forget the "computed column" and make it a regular not null column, with a default to `GETDATE()`, or use an `INSTEAD OF UPDATE/INSERT` trigger to set it.

you can't make a computed column use a function that constantly returns a different value (based on the same parameter values), it must return the same value each time (based on the same parameter values).  Read this: [Deterministic and Nondeterministic Functions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa214775(v=sql.80).aspx)

> All functions are deterministic or nondeterministic:
>
> - **Deterministic functions** always return the same result any time
>     they are called with a specific set of input values.
> - **Nondeterministic functions** may return different results each time
>     they are called with a specific set of input values.
>
> Whether a function is deterministic or nondeterministic is called the
>   **determinism** of the function.
>
> For example, the DATEADD built-in function is deterministic because it
>   always returns the same result for any given set of argument values
>   for its three parameters. GETDATE is not deterministic because it is
>   always invoked with the same argument, yet the value it returns
>   changes each time it is executed.